# Programmatically / Automatically Save Inline Edits on Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable

I have a `<lightning-datatable>` where I want the user to be able to make edits to it, and those changes are automatically saved so that when I call `getSelectedRows()`, I get all the updated data on the selected row.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to leverage the `oncellchange` event which is mentioned in the [Working with Inline Editing section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) of the documentation.

> You can handle the oncancel, **oncellchange**, and onsave actions when the
> cell value changes or is saved

Within that event, you can pull the changes held in `draftValues`.

> The current value that's provided during inline editing.

It'll look something like this where it contains the `id` and only the field that was changed.

`[{"name":"I Changed this", "id": "00000000"}]`

```
<lightning-datatable oncellchange={handleInlineEdit}...
```

```
handleInlineEdit(){
   let draftValues = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').draftValues;
    //pass to server-side apex method to save
    someApexMethod({ dataToUpdate: draftValues })
        .then((result) => {
            this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").draftValues = [];

        });

}
```

You'll then want to pass that to some server-side method (or look to leverage [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record)) to actually save it in Salesforce. Once you get a success from whatever mechanism you use to save it, you'll want to clear the `draftValues` attribute on the datatable as the UI will not show normally (field changed will stay yellow) until that attribute is cleared.

Comment: Ah, `oncellchange` - thank you! I actually won't be saving the data directly to salesforce; I'm using it to make a non-salesforce api call. So I don't think I need to clear the draft values anyway, I just need them to get the most updated values on the datatable so I can pass that to my api.

Comment: great. You still may want to clear the draftValues if you want the UI to look normal so the user knows something happened (if it was sent to other system, etc) and because the changes will keep just piling on within `draftValues` as they continue to edit if you don't clear them out

Answer (score -1):

In the documentation you can find an example with inline editing that will automatically save the changes made to that data. Here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example

Comment: I see the difference there is they've added the `suppress-bottom-bar` attribute...but it doesn't seem to save? At least I don't see the updated data when I run a `getSelectedRows()` - here's an example where I'm using `suppress-bottom-bar` and logging the array from `getSelectedRows()`: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Xkh71RD4Xiwd2L27BlhX

Comment: Besides the link doesn't even answer the question, btw.