# Datatable suppress-bottom-bar attribute - what's the use?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable, inline, inline-editing

In the [`<lightning-datatable>` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification), there's an attribute `suppress-bottom-bar` which "If present, the footer that displays the Save and Cancel buttons is hidden during inline editing."

If you can't save inline edits, what's the point of having them?

I feel like there's something I'm missing here in my understanding of inline editing, saving, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you can't save inline edits, what's the point of having them?

Who said you can't save inline edits with the bottom bar suppressed?

There's two use cases I can think of:

1. Perform some sort of auto-save mechanism as I answered in your
   [Programmatically / Automatically Save Inline Edits on
   Datatable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354951/programmatically-automatically-save-inline-edits-on-datatable) question
2. Give the end user the flexibility to create their own button to
   handle the save themselves if they have specific UI considerations
   in mind.

Since the changes are stored in `draftValues` - users can handle that information as they wish outside the bottom bar "save" mechanism when leveraging `suppress-bottom-bar`

```
handleButtonClick(event){
    let draftValues = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').draftValues;
    //pass to server-side apex method to do actual updating.
}
```

Since you're going around the standard `save` mechanism and implementing your own, you'll also have to explicitly clear out the `draftValues` attribute yourself so the table displays as if the standard `save` button was processed and you only get the changes that haven't been saved when the user inline edits the next time (or clicks the button).

Comment: This is perfect - now that I know I can access the draftValues outside of the `onsave` handler, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the aforementioned usages, if you are nesting an LWC datatable within a Screen Flow you'll want to suppress the datatable's Save button in this way. Otherwise, you'll end up with two Save buttons, one of which only pops up during inline editing.
I'm assuming that you could also run into this same issue if you are wanting to nest the datatable in another component and want the buttons to be either their own separate component or part of the parent.